# Unable to bind 'foo' on class 'Foo'

Tags: flex4, warnings, bindable

I know the 'unable to bind msg' has been asked before but I think in my case is different...

When my application is running on debug mode I get some warnigs I'm not sure how I can solve...

```
[trace] warning: unable to bind to property 'nonCreditRelevantLabel' on class 'com.company.model::Counterparty'

[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="com.company.model.Counterparty")]
public class Counterparty extends CounterpartyBase {

public function get nonCreditRelevantLabel():String {
     return nonCreditRelevant == '1' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}

}
```

I understand that this is a getter, but there is no field as such. It contains some logic for the nonCreditRelevant field which is in CounterpartyBase and also exists in com.company.model.Counterparty on the java side.

I have this in a couple of places, is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding read-only accessors in Flex
http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/binding-read-only-accessors-in-flex